# CodeBuild Output Artifact Should Not Be Compressed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I've got a CodePipeline working with a Java application. I'm pulling the source from GitHub, building a package with Maven using CodeBuild, and deploying to ElasticBeanstalk in the Deploy stage. My problem is that CodeBuild is returning the artifact in a zip file:

```
[Container] 2019/03/21 13:23:07 Expanding target/*.war
[Container] 2019/03/21 13:23:07 Found 1 file(s)
[Container] 2019/03/21 13:23:09 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS Success: true
```

I'm grabbing the resulting war file after the Maven package. I only want the war file to be picked up by ElasticBeanstalk. How I can force CodePipeline/CodeBuild to NOT compress the file?

Comment: It looks like because I'm using an S3 bucket to store the artifacts and maybe because the artifact filename is not changing it's compressing to prevent conflicts. I've tried everything to force it NOT to do this but nothing seems to want to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any type of file, with or without compression in the `artifacts` section of your `buildspec.yaml` file.

Here is an example I am using with docker :

```
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json
```

You will find the full doc of possible values and other examples here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html